# Length of Titlerule

Tags: titlesec, rules, width

I have a picture on the right side of the title. For the title I'm using the underlining with `\titlerule`.

Is it possible to adjust the line in length? I would like to have the line only go to the middle of the document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}   

\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}
    [\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}


\begin{document}    

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.28\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{picture}
  \end{center}

\end{wrapfigure}

\subsection{Personal Data}



\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Date of Birth:} & xxx\\
    \textsc{Address:}   &  xxx\\
    \textsc{Phone:}     & xxx\\
    \textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:xxx}{xxx}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example modifies the inner workings of `\titlerule` to use `\titlewidth` to set the rule width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}
  [\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\let\oldtitleline\titleline
\renewcommand{\titleline}{\oldtitleline*}

\begin{document}    

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\setlength{\titlewidth}{0.5\textwidth}

\subsection{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \textsc{Date of Birth:} & xxx \\
  \textsc{Address:}       & xxx \\
  \textsc{Phone:}         & xxx \\
  \textsc{email:}         & xxx
\end{tabular}

\setlength{\titlewidth}{\textwidth}

\subsection{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \textsc{Date of Birth:} & xxx \\
  \textsc{Address:}       & xxx \\
  \textsc{Phone:}         & xxx \\
  \textsc{email:}         & xxx
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This can't reflow the title text on 50% , it just keeps overflowing