# Starting the titlerule left of the left text margin

Tags: titlesec

I need to make the `\titlerule` in `titlesec` start left of the left text margin, as illustrated in the picture (only the rule, not the title text).

[image]

Here is the MWE that generated the picture:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 
 \usepackage[papersize={17cm,24cm},
    total={134.5mm,209mm},
    inner=43.5mm,
    textwidth=109mm,
    marginparsep=2.5mm,
    marginparwidth=23mm]{geometry}
 
    \usepackage{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\section}%
    {\raggedright\bfseries\uppercase}%
    {\thesection.}{.5em}{}[{\titlerule[0.5pt]}]
 \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{6mm}{2.5mm}
 \titleformat{\subsection}%
    {\titlerule\vspace{5pt}\raggedright\bfseries}%
    {\thesubsection.}{.5em}{}
 \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{5mm}{1mm}
 
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 
    
 \begin{document}
 
 \section{I want the rule to include the left the margin}
 
 \lipsum[2]
 
 \subsection{I want the rule to include the left the margin}
 \lipsum[3]
 
 \end{document}
```

I tried to add `\hspace*{}` before `\titlerule` but I get an error about improper entering in horizontal mode.

```
\titleformat{\subsection}%
    {\hspace*{-23mm}\rule{132mm}{1pt}\vspace{5pt}\raggedright\bfseries}%
    {\thesubsection.}{.5em}{}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Length of Titlerule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299546/length-of-titlerule)

Comment: No, unfortunately. This makes the rule longer, but does not make it start left of the left margin